# Distance Between 2 Substrings

Tags: php, substring

How can I find the distance between two substrings values in a given string?  For example, if I have the word terrific, and I wanted to find the distance between the "i"s (1 space apart).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what if there are three i's in the string, do you want the smallest, the biggest between two that are neighbours, the diestance from most left to most right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$haystack = 'terrific';
$needle = 'i';

$distance = false;
$pos1 = strpos($haystack,$needle);
if ($pos1 !== false) {
   $pos2 = strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos1+1);
   if ($pos2 !== false) {
      $distance = $pos2 - $pos1;
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

or

```
$haystack = 'terrific';
$needle = 'i';

$distance = false;
$needlePositions = array_keys(array_intersect(str_split($haystack),array($needle)));
if (count($needlePositions) > 1) {
   $distance = $needlePositions[1] - $needlePositions[0];
}
```

Comment: +1 OP should probably change `$pos1+1` to `$pos1+strlen($needle)` to use needles that are more than one character in length. Should also decrement `$distance` as `6 - 4 = 2` and OP wants `1`, i.e., one character in between.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few methods with comments inline:

```
// We take our string
$mystring = "terrific";

// Then the first character we want to look for
$mychar1 = "i";
$mychar2 = "i";

// Now we get the position of the first character
$position1 = strpos( $mystring, $mychar1);

// Now we use the last optional parameter offset to get the next i
// We have to go one beyond the previous position for this to work
// Properly
$position2 = strpos( $mystring, $mychar2, ($position1 + 1) );

// Then we get the distance
echo "Distance is: " . ($position2 - $position1) . "\n";

// We can also use strrpos to find the distance between the first and last i
// if there are more than one
$mystring2 = "terrific sunshine";
$position2 = strrpos( $mystring2, $mychar2);

echo "Distance is: " . ($position2 - $position1) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options that you could handle, but this is where to start.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php